# How to find surrogate character in sql column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find surrogate character in SQL Column.
surrogate like (☹,à,�,é,®,ç)

I want to find all this type of character through sql query and replace that character to blank.

Please Help on this..

[image: Error]

Comment: What do you mean by "surrogate" character? How is `à` or `☹` a replacement character, and for what?

Comment: *"I want to find all this type of character through sql query and replace that character to blank."* [REPLACE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  *"Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value."*

Comment: Surrogate character means (☹,à,�,é,®,ç) that type of character. First i want to find this type of character and then replace that character. I want to replace that character to blank in sql column.

Comment: Do you have a list of those characters? I can give you a query to find specific string in all tables and databases then you can update those.

Comment: That explains nothing @RaviShah . Explaining what something is by repeating yourself without an explaining isn't an explanation. Is `8` a surrogate character? What about `^`, `$`, `ü`, `&`, `|`, `)`, `B` or `b`? Why are(n't) they?

Comment: Here, just i given example of that type of characters I want to find that type of character in SQL Column..

Comment: But what does `☹` and `à` have in common? One is an emoticon and the other is an accented `a`. They are nothing alike,

Comment: Wait, all those errors from SalesForce. Seems like a SalesForce Problem.

Comment: Yes, Salesforce not allow this type of character so, I want to remove that type of characters.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. As the error message says, you have a high surrogate followed by a high surrogate. ["Leading, also called high, surrogates are from D800 to DBFF, and trailing, or low, surrogates are from DC00 to DFFF."](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2). You just need to fix the bug causing your text to become corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this function I removed ASCII or surrogate character

```
CREATE FUNCTION RemoveNonASCII (
    @nstring nvarchar(255)
) RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(255)
    SET @Result = ''

    DECLARE @nchar nvarchar(1)
    DECLARE @position int

    SET @position = 1
    WHILE @position <= LEN(@nstring)
    BEGIN
        SET @nchar = SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)
        --Unicode & ASCII are the same from 1 to 255.
        --Only Unicode goes beyond 255
        --0 to 31 are non-printable characters
        IF UNICODE(@nchar) between 32 and 255
            SET @Result = @Result + @nchar
        SET @position = @position + 1
    END

    RETURN @Result
END
```